# asp.net mvc3 localized routing definition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

Hello I'm struggling with the following problem:

I have the following routes, one is **Default** and another for **Localized** links. When I try to access an url Like: `http://domain.com/en/Home/Index` everything seems to be ok. But when I try something like: `http://domain.com/en/Home/Index/5` then I've got a sequence of errors:

**The controller for path '/en/Scripts/jquery.ui.js' could not be found.**

**The controller for path '/en/Content/Images/...' could not be found.**

and so on..

But I have another situation.. When I try to access an url like:

`http://domain.com/en/Home/Index?id=5` everything seems to be ok.

Here are my routes definition:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}",
                                      new {favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.([iI][cC][oO]|[gG][iI][fF])(/.*)?"});

        routes.MapRoute(
            "DefaultLocalized", // Route name
            "{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new {language = "en", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = ""} // Parameter defaults
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new{controller = "Home",action = "Index",id = ""}
            );

    }
```

If somebody have some tips, it will be a pleasure to listen. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the use of direct pointer **href** in linking .css and .js files.

When dealing with virtual/sub directories it's better that all linkings to static files are done through `@Url.Content("~/Scripts/SomePlugin.js")`

but not like the traditional `../../Scripts/SomePlugin.js` linking